# Binary Tree Level Order Traversal using Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

This is a leetcode question.

> Given a binary tree, return the level order traversal of its nodes' values. (ie, from left to right, level by level).
>
> For example:
> Given binary tree `[3, 9, 20, null, null, 15, 7]`,
>
> ```
>     3
>    / \
>   9  20
>     /  \
>    15   7
> ```
>
> return its level order traversal as:
>
> ```
> [
>   [3],
>   [9,20],
>   [15,7]
> ]
> ```

But i am trying it a new way in JavaScript and not going entirely by their solution. So far i am able to print the arrays but

> How can different levels be printed in new rows

Below is my code so far:

```
var levelOrder = function(root) {
let output = [];
let queue = [];
let currentNode = root;
queue.push(currentNode);
let currentLevel = 1;
while(queue.length){
    
    currentNode = queue.shift();
    currentLevel--; //this will ensure we are adding new lines only on next level
    output.push(currentNode);
    
    if(currentNode.left){
        queue.push(currentNode.left);
    }
    if(currentNode.right){
        queue.push(currentNode.right);
    }
    
    if(currentLevel = 0){
        output = output + '/n'; //Insert a new line
        currentLevel = queue.length; //2
    }
}
return output;
};
```

> Input: [3,9,20,null,null,15,7],

```
Expected Output:
[
[3],
[9,20],
[15,7]
]
```

LeetCode Question Link:
[BinaryTreeTraversalUsingBFS](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/)

Comment: Strategy you are looking for is BFS, refer these links - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/binary-tree and https://dsinjs.github.io/binary-tree/#findbfs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're almost there. Not sure what `output = output + '/n';` is for though.

This'd pass through:

```
var levelOrder = function(root) {
    const levels = []

    if(!root) {
        return levels
    }

    const queue = [root]
    while (queue.length){
       const queueLength = queue.length
       const level = []

       for(let i = 0; i < queueLength; i++){

           const node = queue.shift()

           if(node.left){
               queue.push(node.left)
           }
           if(node.right){
               queue.push(node.right)
           }

           level.push(node.val)
       }
       levels.push(level)
   }
    return levels
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Comment: That;s a great solution you hit the bulls eye. I am new to Javascript, so basically you have level array and you are pushing this array to parent array-levels each time child nodes are complete. New line doesn't matter here for arrays it's just for the display, but i suppose if we need to show it as a string then new line has to be entered. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Base on your codebase, I modify it for work.

- Add an index for increasing the output index.
- Use strict equality operator instead of assignment variable.
- Remove `output = output + '/n'`, because output is an array.

```js
var levelOrder = function (root) {
  let output = [];
  let queue = [];
  let currentNode = root;
  queue.push(currentNode);
  let currentLevel = 1;
  let index = 0; // Add an index for increasing the output index

  while (queue.length) {

    currentNode = queue.shift();
    currentLevel--;

    if (!output[index]) { // Set default is an array for each output element in first time
      output[index] = [];
    }

    output[index].push(currentNode.val);

    if (currentNode.left) {
      queue.push(currentNode.left);
    }

    if (currentNode.right) {
      queue.push(currentNode.right);
    }

    if (currentLevel === 0) { // Use strict equality operator to compare 0
      index++; // increase index
      currentLevel = queue.length;
    }
  }

  return output;
};
```

Comment: I think your code will not work for this input :

Input
[1,2,3,4,null,null,5]
stdout
1
[ [ 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 4 ], [ 5 ] ]

Output
[[1],[2,3],[4],[5]]
Expected
[[1],[2,3],[4,5]]

Answer (score 0):

This is the recursion solution to it

```
    var levelOrder = function(root) {
    let result =[];
    if(!root)return result;
    if(!root.left && !root.right){
        result.push([root.val]);
        return result;
    }
    const pushIntoResult =(node, level) =>{
        if(!node) return;
        if(!result[level]){
            result.push([]);
        }
        result[level].push(node.val);
        pushIntoResult(node.left, level+1);
        pushIntoResult(node.right, level+1);
    }
    pushIntoResult(root, 0);
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this bit modification in @Ahmad Atrach' code

```
const dfs = (node,result,level) => {

if(!node) return;
if(!result[level]){
    result.push([]);
}
result[level].push(node.val);
dfs(node.left,result, level+1);
dfs(node.right,result, level+1);
}
var levelOrder = function(root) {

  if(!root) return [];
  let result = [];
  dfs(root,result,0);

  return result;
};
```